# discord.js detect multiple channel deletes and multiple bans

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to make a anti nuke bot and I am wondering how I would go about detecting if there have been X numbers of channels deleted or members banned between an Y amount of time. any ideas of how to detect this would be extremely useful.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways you could do this. One thing to note is that it looks like when a channel is deleted from discord it's not a 'soft delete' - meaning the data is gone.

What you could do in this instance is create an application that consumes the [discord API](https://discordapp.com/developers/docs/intro), checking every x days / hours / minutes and saving a record of all channels / members to a database.

On the next run of the application it will compare the returned channels to the data from the last run, alerting the users if there is a large discrepancy.